# jqueryUI datepicker onSelect not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using the jquery datepicker.
as soon as a date in selected(onSelect) i need to complete a function. 
But my datepicker never fires the onselect.
my code is:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    buttonImage: "/images/calendar.png",
    constrainInput: true,
    defaultDate: new Date(1975, 1 - 1, 1),
    yearRange: "1900:2000",
    onSelect: function () {
        alert('create function');
    }
});
```

If i set the onSelect with $.datepicker.setDefaults({}); then the onSelect works. But i cant use this because different functions need to be fired with different datepickers.

Help will be much appreciated.

Comment: looks fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/G3RGW/1/

Comment: Is it a browser specific issue, Which browsers have you tried? Upon asking this question, I decided to go to the JSfiddle link in IE8 and I now know that JSfiddle does not support IE8 :-)

Comment: Try removing all the other options and just have onSelect.  Perhaps there is an error with one of those.  I don't see any issue though. The other thing to look for is event bubbling.  Are you calling return false on that object?

Comment: Tried 'onselect' didnt work, tried different browser(was using chrome), didn't work. tried the jsfiddle and that one works fine. Maybe this helps: the code is in a seperate JS file.

Comment: Are you making sure the dom is loaded?  $(document).ready(function(){ //your datepicker code }

Comment: Yes, the function that holds the code is called within the $(document).ready() i have also tried to put the code directly within the $(document).ready() but this also doesn't work.

Comment: can you please check how many elements are there with class "datepicker" as there can be multiple elements so try with id

Comment: I finally found it out. Someone in my team created some javascript that messed it all up. Sorry for the bother and thank you all for your time.